# Connect Excel to PostgreSQL via ODBC

Tags: excel, postgresql, unicode, odbc, ansi

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database table from Excel via the PostgreSQL ODBC 32-bit driver.

In Excel, I go to Data>Get Data> From Other Sources> From ODBC. I navigate to the ODBC data source I set up, enter the credentials, and it clearly connects as the available tables appear. The preview fails and the query fails when I hit "Load" giving the error:

```
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] Error while executing the query
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=PostgreSQL
    OdbcErrors=Table
```

[image: Picture of Error Message]

When I test the connection in ODBC admin it is successful. I have tried both the ANSI and Unicode drivers. TIBCO Spotfire connects to the ODBC datasource and pulls the data in just fine.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any special permissions/restrictions on viewing the specific table from a DBA standpoint? Have you tried using a full admin's credentials?

Comment: Can you please showing at least the structure of the database and the table name? Especially if there is a underscore `_` in it like `the_name`?

Comment: @JosephSerido Not that I am aware of. This is a hosted, AWS RDS PostgreSQL database. I am using the credentials I set up with the instance. Every other viewing platform like Spotfire or PGadmin, is reading the table(s) with no extra effort.

Comment: @AxelRichter yes, sorry. It contained a customer name so I didn't want to. Neither the database name nor the table name contains an underscore. The formats are 'ABCquickbase' and 'CompanyTracking', respectively. The structure of 'CompanyTracking' is 131 records by 14 fields. It should be noted that the error occurs for both tables in the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the latest psqlODBC driver, which is *psqlodbc_09_06_0500* at the time I'm writing this. I have access to my PostgreSQL server logs. Here's the error message and the offending query:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ta" at character 553
STATEMENT:  select ta.attname, ia.attnum, ic.relname, n.nspname, tc.relname from pg_catalog.pg_attribute ta, pg_catalog.pg_attribute ia, pg_catalog.pg_class tc, pg_catalog.pg_index i, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n, pg_catalog.pg_class ic where tc.relname = 'rates' AND n.nspname = 'public' AND tc.oid = i.indrelid AND n.oid = tc.relnamespace AND i.indisprimary = 't' AND ia.attrelid = i.indexrelid AND ta.attrelid = i.indrelid AND ta.attnum = i.indkey[ia.attnum-1] AND (NOT ta.attisdropped) AND (NOT ia.attisdropped) AND ic.oid = i.indexrelid order by ia.attnumselect ta.attname, ia.attnum, ic.relname, n.nspname, NULL from pg_catalog.pg_attribute ta, pg_catalog.pg_attribute ia, pg_catalog.pg_class ic, pg_catalog.pg_index i, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n where ic.relname = 'rates_pkey' AND n.nspname = 'public' ANDic.oid = i.indexrelid AND n.oid = ic.relnamespace AND ia.attrelid = i.indexrelid AND ta.attrelid = i.indrelid AND ta.attnum = i.indkey[ia.attnum-1] AND (NOT ta.attisdropped) AND (NOT ia.attisdropped) order by ia.attnum
```

Here's the context around character 553: `order by ia.attnumselect ta.attname, ia.attnum`. Note that it's missing a comma between two field names.

I was able to get it working with *psqlodbc_09_06_0200*, which is about a year old. Since it sounds like you use 32-bit Office, you can download *psqlodbc_09_06_0200-x86.zip* from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/. (Use x64 if you have 64-bit Office installed.)

You might be able to experiment with driver versions between *psqlodbc_09_06_0200-x86.zip* and *psqlodbc_09_06_0500-x86.zip* as the bug was presumably introduced somewhere between those two versions.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue but using PostgreSQL Unicode (x64) driver version 10.03 which is a later version than the above driver. Do you know any other way of resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can skip this error by removing the navigate step and querying the information you need throw an SQL statement.

For example if you want to retry some information from LineItemExport the default query is something like this:

```
let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=name", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    quickbase_Database = Source{[Name="quickbase",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    public_Schema = quickbase_Database{[Name="public",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    LineItemExport = public_Schema{[Name="LineItemExport",Kind="View"]}[Data]
in
    LineItemExport
```

You have to change the source step in the query editor or change the code to something like this:

```
let
    Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=name", "select * from public.LineItemExport")
in
    Source
```

This is the way you can came over the error, otherwise you should try to change your drivers version.

Comment: Have you found any other solutions to solving this issue, as I feel this is a bit long-winded for some users, especially those who are not used to changing / reading code. Unfortunately I have run into the same issue as OP and your solution works, but it's not ideal for someone who frequently pulls in 5+ data sources a day.

Interestingly you can pull this through using the "Legacy Data Connection Wizard" - but this doesn't have the nice search bar UI.

Comment: @rup  Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "Legace Data Connection Wizzard"?  Or maybe you found other solution?  The one offered here  does not allow for query folding so not workable for me unfortunately.  Thanks

Comment: @Confounded this is best method to connect to a PostgreSQL db in Excel:

**1** [Download the PostgreSQL ODBC driver for Windows](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) -I use v10.3
**2** Enter your DB credentials. Go Start > ODBC Data Sources (64 bit)
**3** Open Excel > File > Options > Data > Tick the 'From Data Connection Wizard (Legacy)' option
**4** Click Excel Data Tab>Get Data>Legacy Wizards>From Data Connection Wizard (Legacy) > ODBC DSN > [Your ODBC Datasource name] > Choose View
**5** Data loads into table and you can right click & refresh for live data